# SQL Server for Linux 2019 - Windows Authentication not working

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, redhat, linux

Hoping to pick the brains of those more knowledgeable than me. I've been trying to set up a SQL Server 2019 instance on Linux; specifically on AWS using AMI **amzn2-x86_64-SQL_2019_Standard-2019.11.12**

I've followed the steps to connect the instance to our domain, and am able to successfully login using my domain credentials. sssd.conf below:

```
[sssd]
domains = [domain name]
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/[domain name]
ad_server = [FQDN of Domain Controller]
ad_domain = [domain name]
krb5_realm = [DOMAIN NAME]
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
access_provider = ad
```

I've followed all the steps on the MSDN documentation on how to set up Windows Authentiation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-linux-ver15

But whenever I try to login to the SQL Server using my domain credentials I receive the following error:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication..
```

And in the mssql-server logs (using systemctl status mssql-server -l) I see the following:

```
Apr 22 04:47:04 [SERVER NAME.DOMAIN NAME] sqlservr[3243]: 2020-04-22 04:47:04.24 Logon       Error: 17806, Severity: 20, State: 14.
Apr 22 04:47:04 [SERVER NAME.DOMAIN NAME] sqlservr[3243]: 2020-04-22 04:47:04.24 Logon       SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x80090304, state 14 while establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has been closed. Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed. The operating system error code indicates the cause of failure.
The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted   [CLIENT: [IP ADDRESS]]
Apr 22 04:47:04 [SERVER NAME.DOMAIN NAME] sqlservr[3243]: 2020-04-22 04:47:04.25 Logon       Error: 18452, Severity: 14, State: 1.
Apr 22 04:47:04 [SERVER NAME.DOMAIN NAME] sqlservr[3243]: 2020-04-22 04:47:04.25 Logon       Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication. [CLIENT: [IP ADDRESS]]
```

The error would suggest an issue contacting the Local Security Authority, so I've double checked my krb5.conf file and don't see any obvious issues:

```
# Configuration snippets may be placed in this directory as well
includedir /etc/krb5.conf.d/

includedir /var/lib/sss/pubconf/krb5.include.d/
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true
 rdns = false
 pkinit_anchors = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
# default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}
 udp_preference_limit=0

 default_realm = [DOMAIN NAME]
[realms]
# EXAMPLE.COM = {
#  kdc = kerberos.example.com
#  admin_server = kerberos.example.com
# }

 [DOMAIN NAME] = {
 kdc = [Domain Controller 1 FQDN]:88
 kdc = [Domain Controller 2 FQDN]:88
 kdc = [Domain Controller 3 FQDN]:88
}

[domain_realm]
# .example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
# example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
 [DOMAIN NAME] = [DOMAIN NAME]
 .[DOMAIN NAME] = [DOMAIN NAME]
```

And the fact that I can login using my AD credentials to me suggests there's no overarching issue contacting the domain controllers.

Any tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated on where to go next with this!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming here looking for the solution, it is all about the keytab file.

This is a good tutotial
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16

If you have a windows server or DC you can use ktpass like the example below.

```
ktpass /princ MSSQLSvc/<fully qualified domain name of host machine>:<tcp port>@CONTOSO.COM /ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL /crypto aes256-sha1 /mapuser <DomainName>\<UserName> /out mssql.keytab -setpass -setupn /kvno <#> /pass <StrongPassword>

ktpass /princ MSSQLSvc/<fully qualified domain name of host machine>:<tcp port>@CONTOSO.COM /ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL /crypto rc4-hmac-nt /mapuser <DomainName>\<UserName> /in mssql.keytab /out mssql.keytab -setpass -setupn /kvno <#> /pass <StrongPassword>

ktpass /princ MSSQLSvc/<netbios name of the host machine>:<tcp port>@CONTOSO.COM /ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL /crypto aes256-sha1 /mapuser <DomainName>\<UserName> /in mssql.keytab /out mssql.keytab -setpass -setupn /kvno <#> /pass <StrongPassword>

ktpass /princ MSSQLSvc/<netbios name of the host machine>:<tcp port>@CONTOSO.COM /ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL /crypto rc4-hmac-nt /mapuser <DomainName>\<UserName> /in mssql.keytab /out mssql.keytab -setpass -setupn /kvno <#> /pass <StrongPassword>

ktpass /princ <UserName>@CONTOSO.COM /ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL /crypto aes256-sha1 /mapuser <DomainName>\<UserName> /in mssql.keytab /out mssql.keytab -setpass -setupn /kvno <#> /pass <StrongPassword>

ktpass /princ <UserName>@CONTOSO.COM /ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL /crypto rc4-hmac-nt /mapuser <DomainName>\<UserName> /in mssql.keytab /out mssql.keytab -setpass -setupn /kvno <#> /pass <StrongPassword>
```

If like me your DC is a Samba domain controller it is best to use samba-tools.

```bash
sudo samba-tool domain exportkeytab mssql.keytab --principal {username or SPN} --password {user password}
```

You have to do this for your service account AND ALL your SPNs. Repeating the command for each will append to the file.

On Linux you can check your keytab file with

```
sudo klist -kte mssql.keytab
```

Make sure all your SPNs are listed.

Then follow the instruction in the linked article to configure SQL Server to use your service account and keytab file.

If your SQL server is a VM take a snapshot before making the changes. Luckily I did because the 1st times it didn't work and trying to update the key file crash SQL server.

Good luck!

Note to Admins: Yeah I know, linking to articles is not the best way to answer question but the post was already long and rewriting something I know works seemed redundant as the crux if the answer is getting the keytab file right.